# Change images slider step in TensorBoard

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

TensorBoard 1.1.0's images history. I would like to set the slider's position (on top of the black image with 7) more precisely, to be able to select any step. Now I can only select e.g. between steps 2050 or 2810. Is that possible?

Maybe a place in sources where the 10 constant is hardcoded?

- [image]

Comment: Sorry, how could I change the tensorboard backend code? I am in Ubuntu but cannot find the source code path... Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I managed to do this by changing [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/0e1af87fee863542796bddffd398f3cceba482dc/tensorboard/backend/application.py#L58) line in TensorBoard backend

Comment: I would recommend that you link to a specific commit instead of master, as the line reference is likely to break otherwise -- I think it already did.

Comment: Sorry, how could I change the tensorboard backend code? I am in Ubuntu but cannot find the source code path... Thank you!

Comment: @Turtle Please also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43743761/2184122    to find the code, do a 'which python'.  Then cd into that directory and navigate into the subdirectories.  You will need write permissions to make a change.

Answer (score 70):

I answered this question over there "[TensorBoard doesn't show all data points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43702546/tensorboard-doesnt-show-all-data-points/52178270#52178270)", but this seems to be more popular so I will quote it here.

You don't have to change the source code for this, there is a flag called `--samples_per_plugin`.

Quoting from the `help` command

> --samples_per_plugin: An optional comma separated list of plugin_name=num_samples pairs to explicitly
>       specify how many samples to keep per tag for that plugin. For unspecified plugins, TensorBoard
>       randomly downsamples logged summaries to reasonable values to prevent out-of-memory errors for long
>       running jobs. This flag allows fine control over that downsampling. Note that 0 means keep all
>       samples of that type. For instance, "scalars=500,images=0" keeps 500 scalars and all images. Most
>       users should not need to set this flag.
>       (default: '')

So if you want to have a slider of 100 images, use:

`tensorboard --samples_per_plugin images=100`

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. thnx!

Comment: happy to help. :)

Comment: For people stumbling across this question, this is the updated answer

Answer (score 7):

This question is covered in the [FAQ](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/README.md#is-my-data-being-downsampled-am-i-really-seeing-all-the-data):

> **Is my data being downsampled? Am I really seeing all the data?**
>
> TensorBoard uses [reservoir sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) to downsample your data so that it
>   can be loaded into RAM. You can modify the number of elements it will
>   keep per tag in tensorboard/backend/application.py. See [this
>   StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43702546/tensorboard-doesnt-show-all-data-points/) for some more information.