# PyTorch TensorBoard write frequency

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, tensorboard

I'm trying to write my training and validation losses to tensorboard using torch (torch.utils.tensorboard) and it looks like it only writes up to 1000 data points, no matter what the actual number of iterations are. For example, running the following code,

```
writer1 = SummaryWriter('runs/1')
writer2 = SummaryWriter('runs/2')

for i in range(2000):
    writer1.add_scalar('tag', 1, i)

for i in range(20000):
    writer2.add_scalar('tag', 1, i)
```

both yield 1000 points exactly when examining and downloaded csv, and even on the tensorboard dashboard, the first points start at steps 5 and 18 and increment such that the total number of steps are 1000, rather than 2,000 and 20,000.

I don't know if this is tensorboard's default behaviour or if its PyTorch's decision, but either way, is there a way to write every single step?

Comment: Can you elaborate your setup more? The code you have shown above works for me.

Comment: @UmangGupta Are you able to get the entire 2000 and 20000 points using my sample code? For me, when I zoom in I can see that the first point is not at step 0, but rather at 5. Could you also try to download the csv and take a look at how many rows of data you get? I'm getting exactly 1001 including the header, no matter how many iterations there actually are

Comment: Ah interesting. You are correct. I never realized this problem until now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43702546/tensorboard-doesnt-show-all-data-points?rq=1). So the SummaryWriter is saving at every epoch, but to load everything, tensorboard has to be started with the flag `--samples_per_plugin scalars=0`. 0 tells tensorboard to load all points, while 100 would mean a total of 100 points for example

To sum up, I started tensorboard with the command `tensorboard --logdir=logs --samples_per_plugin scalars=0`

Comment: @SzymonMaszke Thanks for reminding me, but apparently I have to wait a day before accepting my own answer